# Chrome: can you configure its "failed to load resource" timeout?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, timeout

I noticed that when I enter a domain for which Chrome (and Chromium) has a client rule to block certain resources from loading (therefore giving a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" "error"), I have to wait a very long time for some sort of timeout to occur before this on-purpose "error" gets thrown.

I find it silly that the browser forces me to wait for a resource to load, even when it knows that this specific resource has been BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT.

My question is either: Can I configure Chrome to not wait for stuff which has been blocked by client? Or, can I hack it somehow to shorten Chrome's resource loading timeout time?

Can any of this be achieved through a configuration or extension or even a script somehow?

Comment: In case anyone thinks to ask, I have disabled "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" and "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" in Settings.